# Java Generics are modeled in ArgoUML with Template Parameter? How it works?

Tags: java, generics, uml, argouml

Suppose I have an operation that receives a parameter java Set and returns Set. How can I model that in ArgoUML? It seems I have to create a class “Set” with a Template Parameter, but I’m unable to find out how it works.

Comment: Sets and other Collections should not be modeled as Classes in UML. You should consider using to-n relations instead (which can be ordered for lists etc.). For other purposes template parameters can be used to model generics... please change your question in that case :)

Comment: You know, besides data type, ArgoUML only let me configure in/out/return properties for operation parameters. I thought there should be some property to indicate that my parameter is multivalued. Is that what you are saying? In the absence of the property, I think I could use template parameters, but I still could not understand how they work…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way of seeing what capabilities are supported in ArgoUML and how they map to the UI is to reverse engineer a simple example that does what you want.  Templated classes (TemplateParameters, Bindings, etc) are incompletely implemented in ArgoUML 0.34 (the current release).  If you reverse engineer a class using the generic placeholder `E`, you'll end up with not only a Template Parameter named `E`, but another class named `E` as well, so it's getting a little confused.

Unfortunately, I don't think the suggestion to use multiplicity (how you say things are multi-valued in UML) will work in this case because a) a `Set` has additional semantics regarding uniqueness, etc and b) you presumably want to show the generalization to `java.util.Set`, not just any old random set implementation.

You can see the placeholder for this in UI in the Template Parameters field at the bottom of the property panel for a Class.  It will allow you to create a Template Parameter, but not do much else with it.

Probably the best you can do for right now is to just type your input and return parameters as plain old `Set` and forego the specificity of a strongly typed `Set`.